# Ajax in SharePoint 2013 Webparts

Tags: 2013

I have development experience in SharePoint 2010 but 2013 is new for me as branding is different in 2013 version. To start my question first i need to provide basic info so you guys can answer me in a better way.

**SharePoint Environment:**
SharePoint 2013 (Enterprise version)

**Tools:**
Visual Studio 2013 (Ultimate version)

**Scope of my work:**
I need to develop a Visual WebPart to retrieve some fields from SharePoint list and display in repeater control with pagination with AJAX functionality so page wont post.

Now my question is how to incorporate AJAX in Visual Webpart development to achieve my goal using 4.5 framework.

For this I have tried http://sharepointajax.codeplex.com and following the tutorial
http://andreaswijayablog.blogspot.com/2013/12/ajax-control-toolkit-with-sharepoint.html?showComment=1407581200289#c583061232821173847

Followed the above tutorial but can't get success in following the instruction which says "5. Replace the default ScriptManager in your masterpage with the ToolkitScriptManager"

getting the error "The ID 'ScriptManager' is already used by another control." cause .master automatically generates this and I am unable to edit .master directly to comment out or remove ...

OR is there any alternate using JQuery or something to achieve this if I dont want to use AjaxToolKit? any suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

Try to delete Scrpt Manager. At my Code in Sharepoint 2010 it's Worked. You Have got a two Script Manager on Your site. One Is on Master Page and the decound is on Your Webpart. That's Why You are geting this Error. Always You Should only Have one Script Manager.

Comment: Well this is what my question is HOW? I can't delete from .master cause you can't touch it directly. I tried disassociate the .html file with .master and made change but this way it overrides the .master change once you associate .html again.

Comment: There is a Control of Sharepoint Script Manager.

Comment: And if I good remember i Used the same control on master page. I find out today at work and told You.

Comment: Ok i find a solution. Do this like article told: http://andreaswijayablog.blogspot.com/2013/12/ajax-control-toolkit-with-sharepoint.html?m=1

Comment: well if you see the name there Zahid Zia ..thats me :)

Comment: But You write it today ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can also make use of `Update Panel`.

> UpdatePanel controls are a central part of AJAX functionality in
>   ASP.NET. They are used with the ScriptManager control to enable
>   partial-page rendering. Partial-page rendering reduces the need for
>   synchronous postbacks and complete page updates when only part of the
>   page has to be updated. Partial-page rendering improves the user
>   experience because it reduces the screen flicker that occurs during a
>   full-page postback and improves Web page interactivity.

Source: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.updatepanel.aspx

I have used it in one of the web parts here http://www.sharepointnadeem.com/2011/10/ajax-in-sharepoint-2010-webparts.html

Comment: Nadeem,

in 2013 its different. I am talking about .master which you cant touch in 2013..in 2010 I did the same long time back.